# Find and replace with regular expressions in Intellij

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I got the following string:

```
http://www.foo.com/images/bar/something/image.gif|png
```

I would like to replace all the occurences of such string as:

`<someTag>/images/bar/something/image.gif|png</someTag>`

How can I achieve this using a regEx?

Comment: Clarify your question please.

Comment: <img alt="blablalba" class="c-Brand__logo" src="http://foo.com/partners/css/united/header/images/mp_logo.png" alt="">

Comment: I need to replace only the http://foo.com/patners/css/header/ part  with a tag

Comment: So what prevents you from using Idea's own replace command in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

To open Replace in Path popup press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or on mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
If you want to switch everywhere in your project, make sure the scope is `In Project`.

Make sure `Regex?` is checked and put the next values in the boxes:

`(http://)([a-zA-Z.0-9]*)([a-zA-Z.-/0-9#?%&|]*)`

`<someTag>$3</someTag>`

You will need to make sure all the characters you need are in the expression. For example strings with `@` will not be replaced as expected.

The way this works is the patterns matched are matched in 3 groups and by using the parenthesis and then only the 3d group is being used to replace the string found.

Example:

[image: Example]

Good luck!